# Appending item to list in Python overwring all existing elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am writing a script to read a .osu file and convert it to specific objects. This has to be done multiple times for each "hitobject"

The reading part works fine, however appending the object is the problem

When appending the object, it seems to overwrite all existing elements in the list. I can not for the life of me figure out why this is happening.

I have tried creating a "temp" list, which stores the objects in a local list instead of the "self.notes" list, still the same issue.

I believe the error is occurring in this part of the file:

```
if hitobjline != -1:
            hitobjects = self.file_lines[hitobjline+1:]
            for i in hitobjects:
                ln = i[:i.find(':')].split(',')
                new_note = [NoteType.Circle, NoteType.Hold][int(ln[3] == '128')]
                add_note = File.Note
                add_note.NoteTypeByte = ln[3]

                add_note.Note_Number = int(ln[0])
                add_note.Time = int(ln[2])
                add_note.NoteType = new_note
                add_note.Raw = ln
                self.notes.append(add_note)
                print(ln, ln[3], ln[3] == '128', new_note, add_note.NoteType)
```

For background, the .osu files have a syntax like: x,y,time,type,hit,end:stuff-i-dont-need-to-worry-about

I expected an out put of `self.notes[0].NoteType` to be `osureader.NoteType.Hold` as the first line of the file is `192,192,410,128,0,2974:0:0:0:0:` (the 128 indicating the 'Hold'

However, I get, osureader.NoteType.Circle, the last line of the file.

Comment: Can you perhaps try `add_note = File.Note.copy()`

Comment: Do self.notes.append(add_note.copy())

Comment: `add_note.copy()` and `add_note = File.Note.copy()` both return attribute errors. Any other suggestions?